# Is cutting EQ scientifically different than boosting EQ?

Tags: filters, audio

This is a fairly standard belief in the audio production scene that cutting EQ is somehow "cleaner" than boosting EQ. You hear arguments like there being different phase characteristics or whatever. The more careful arguers refer to psychoacoustics (that it's easier to listen to the effects of cuts, rather than boosts).

However, is there a difference in the filter in terms of cutting and boosting? And which one is "cleaner"?

Comment: i have trouble mixing *"scientific"* distinction and *"somehow 'cleaner'"*.  you gotta define what you mean.  and, to be scientific, you have to define in tangible observation how "clean" is measured.

Comment: Clean means that the algorithm causes no artefacts, but produces what one expects it to. Or produces only non-audible artefacts. It's very clear in an EQ application, what this means.

Comment: gotta define what an "artifact" is.  i will venture into a little speculation about what you mean:  whether it's *boost* or *cut*, if we're good at writing our DSP code, we can make **absolutely** certain that the processing satisfies the criteria for Linear and Time-Invariant.  at least to the extent before any clipping or quantization problems if the signal is so low that it's close to the LSB floor.  if clipping or non-dithered quantization happens, there may be artifacts whether it's *boost* or *cut*.  [....]

Comment: ... that said, if there are artifacts in the original audio that seem to be composed of frequencies components around the boost/cut frequency of the bell-shaped EQ, then boosting it will cause more effect of the artifacts than cutting it.  in addition, if the tails of the bell-shaped EQ is at 0 dB, then *boost* will never decrease the output level and *cut* will never increase the output level.  boosting the output level can possibly lead to clipping, which can be argued to be an "artifact."  i think it's possible that a **very narrow** boost or cut may cause a ringing artifact in either case.

Comment: Do you mean "cutting one band by x dB" vs "boosting all other bands by x dB"?  In this case, yes there will be a definite difference in the frequency response plot, not just a gain difference (unless it's a digital EQ specifically designed to not do this, but I suspect that is uncommon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very compelling reason for preferring cutting over boosting. Assuming you are using the typical bell-response parametric EQ bands, then you will see a significant phase distortion around the resonant frequency, i.e. the frequency you're boosting or attenuating. (There is an exception to this rule: Linear phase EQs that are often used for mastering do not show this phenomenon. Those only exist as digital implementations however and have other problems.)

The most noticable effect of the phase distortion is that it comes with a certain group delay around the resonant frequency, and especially narrow changes can result in audible post-ringing and temporal distortion of transients.

Now if you're boosting what you want to hear more, you introduce this kind of problem exactly in the band that you want to give more prominence. Cutting also introduces the same issues, but you usually cut what you don't want to hear as prominently. So cutting will move the phase artefacts to the sonically less important frequency range while boosting will place it right where you don't want it.

That's the theory at least. In practice, the rule can be relaxed in most cases. The negative effects of resonant phase distortion greatly depend on the derivative of the phase response with respect to the frequency. That means that resonances with very small bandwidth will result in greater issues than wide band resonances. And this is absolute bandwidth, not relative bandwidth. This means for a typical EQ band that has a bandwidth proportional to the center frequency ("constant-Q filter"), the bandwidth automatically gets larger for higher frequencies.

So a bell EQ at a few kHz will have a large bandwidth, even if it has a rather high resonance. Therefore cutting vs boosting doesn't make a huge difference for higher frequencies. It does however get relevant for frequencies in the lower mid and the bass range, especially when you're using high Q-factors.

Answer (score 1):

As a live sound engineer I know this saying all too well. I don't really think it has to do with the actual design of the EQ. Rather it is the overall practical consequence it has on cumulative gain and definition of the mix.

Passive analogue EQ designs actually work by attenuation and a final makeup gain step. So in that sense you never really boost a certain frequency - you attenuate it less than the other bands. Others truly boost a specific area by first splitting the bands, then amplify and sum. The actual filter designs have great impact on how linear the device is in the end and would have a great influence on that old "never-boost-always-cut" saying. In active EQ designs there are other reasons such as phase displacements (for additional info on passive and active designs see [this article](https://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jul07/articles/qa0707_4.htm)).

No, I think the old saying is rather related to gain and clarity/definition of the whole as such. Typically you would set the input gain and monitor the levels so the signal is in the safe range, perhaps make a few local EQ adjustments (local in the sense that you set these band levels listening to the source isolated). Then when the first round of getting things through the board is done, you start making the more creative interrelated adjustments. But at this point you are already done with the first gain round, and EQ boost could make the signal go too hot and this tendency builds up across the channels.
The other point about clarity and definition is simply this: do not add what you need - remove what you *do not* need. While that makes good sense when tweaking a channel isolated, it is a rather useless point if you need additional high end on a channel compared to the rest: you'd have to lower the top on all other channels ;-)

Comment: "Many analogue EQ designs actually work by attenuation and a final makeup gain step."  Why do you say that?  In my experience, the unity gain position behaves just like a unity-gain op-amp.

Comment: I was thinking about passive buffered designs - I adjusted the answer.